# Android shared element transitions not working with <include> tag

Tags: android, android-layout, shared-element-transition

I've been using shared element transitions in my app using `ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation()` and `ActivityCompat.startActivityForResult()` with some of the following XML code:

```
...

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:transitionName="@string/transition_1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="16sp"
    android:paddingBottom="16sp">

    ...

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

...
```

Everything here works great.

However, since I am using the content inside my `CardView` multiple times, I decided to move it to a new layout and use `<include>` to reference it.

Here's the new layout file:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    ...

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

And the old file:

```
...

<include layout="@layout/my_card_content"
    android:transitionName="@string/transition_1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="16sp"
    android:paddingBottom="16sp" />

...
```

Now, for some reason, the shared element transitions don't seem to work.

How should I fix this issue?

Answer (score 4):

Turns out the problem is because **I need to include the `android:transitionName` inside the layout with my card** so that my card layout looks like this:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:transitionName="@string/transition_1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    ...

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Meaning that it is not needed in my `<include>` tag:

```
<include layout="@layout/my_card_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="16sp"
    android:paddingBottom="16sp" />
```